# Fake comments web application?

Tags: comments

I'm a big fan of the [twat-o-tron](http://ifyoulikeitsomuchwhydontyougolivethere.com/the-twat-o-tron/) at ifyoulikeitsomuchwhydontyougolivethere.com which produces fake crazy comments, along the lines of:

> Oh god not this again!. I read in the Sun that Labour is denying our freedoms. All Englishmen should string them lal up. No doubt this is illegal under theeu human rights cat!
>
> **What_happened_to_my_country Welwyn** Garden City

Are there any other similar automatic comment creators like this?

Answer (score 1):

Find some text (like a Wikipedia article) and enter it into the [Markov Text Synthesizer.](http://www.beetleinabox.com/mkv_input.html)

For more information see Jeff Atwood's blog entry: [Markov and You](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/markov-and-you.html)

> In Finally, a Definition of Programming I Can Actually Understand I marvelled at particularly strange and wonderful comment left on this blog. Some commenters wondered if that comment was generated through Markov chains. I considered that, but I had a hard time imagining a text corpus input that could possibly produce output so profoundly weird.

There's also a Stack-App to [generate similar spam](https://stackapps.com/questions/306/flack-overstow-generate-spam-from-trilogy-posts) from StackExchange content.